# Finding and outputting a specific substring for R script

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to run a script for an bioinformatics/visualization R tool. Our lab's bioinfomatician is currently on vacation and nobody else in this lab has a working knowledge on anything pertaining to programing.
The script I'm using takes the specified files and uses some regex for internal usage and renaming and has been written to accomodate somebody elses naming scheme.

My current scheme is something along the lines of:

*geneName* *secondGeneName* *generationNumber* *sampleNumber*-*alleleNumber*_M13r.ab1

So for example: 
`CDH 13 F1 1-1_M13r.ab1
CDH 13 F1 1-2_M13r.ab1
CDH 13 F1 2-1_M13r.ab1
...`

geneName and secondGeneName are always three letters and two digits respectively

generationNumber is either F1 or F2

sampleNumber has a range from one to two digits

alleleNumber right now is only one digit

The script needs two sets of Outputs like this:

*sampleNumber*-*alleleNumber*
e.g.`1-1
1-2
2-1
...`

and just *sampleNumber*
e.g.

`1
1
2` (digits in front of the Hyphen)

I've been trying to come up with some regex but cannot get the right outputs

I tried:`gsub("[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*([:digit:]-[:digit:])_.?.ab1","\\1", arrayOfFilenames)`

as well as just brutishly: `gsub("[[:alnum:]]*[[:alnum:]]*[[:space:]]([[:alnum:]]*-[[:digit:]])_.*?.ab1", "\\1", arrayOfFilenames)`

but nothing comes out right.

The obvious brute force solution would be just to rename the few hundred files I have to fit the original naming scheme but that could take me a few hours :(

I'd be happy for any help on this (and if you have time to explain please also give me a brief overview on what your solution actually does).

Cheers,
Max

Comment: Why not `substr`?

Comment: Found out the right command: `gsub("[[:alnum:]][[:space:]][[:alnum:]][[:space:]][[:alnum:]][[:space:]]([[:digit:]]-[[:digit:]])_.*?.ab1", "\\1", arrayOfFilenames)`.
She ain't pretty but works. If someone has got a better solution please tell me.

Comment: @djhurio could you please elaborate? I am not very familiar with R and can't see how `substr` would help me here.

Comment: See the answer by @amrrs.

Comment: You may do it like this: 1) add `library(stringr)`, 2) use `str_match(x, "^[a-zA-Z]{3}\\s+\\d{2}\\s+F[12]\\s+(\\d{1,2}-(\\d)).*\\.ab1$")`, and take Columns 1 and 2. (See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xid0v2/1)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need regex? Why not `substr`?

```
> filename <- 'CDH 13 F1 1-1_M13r.ab1'
> filename
[1] "CDH 13 F1 1-1_M13r.ab1"
> substr(filename,11,13)
[1] "1-1"
> substr(filename,11,11)
[1] "1"
```

Update:

```
> substr(filename,11,grep('_',strsplit(filename,'')[1][[1]])-1)
[1] "1-1"
```

Comment: Since not all files are uniform. I could also have `CDH 13 F1 1-13_M13r.ab1` which would return me `1-1`; same as your example. I know this is my bad naming scheme making things difficult.
I could do something along the lines of `if (substr(filename, 14, 14) ==" " {return(substr(filename, 11, 14)} else {return(substr(filename, 11, 13)}` But what if my data exceeds 2 digits...